# how to change the image size

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

In this piece of my code i want to change the image when i click on it. How i can do this?

I use `img.setOnClickListenser` but really i don't know what the code must put in it

```
        @Override
           public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_img2, container, false);
            Log.d("start_new_frg gallery_img ", "ok");
             back = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1); 

            if (id == -1 ){

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "bad Entry ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                onBackPressed(); 
                getActivity().finish(); 

            }


            imgv = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            String ROOT = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/POSTSIMAGES/";
            final Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ROOT+String.valueOf(g.getId())+"q.jpg");


            File f = new File(ROOT+String.valueOf(g.getId())+"q.jpg");
            temp=ROOT;
            if(!f.exists()){
                imgv.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_and);
                }
            else 
            {
                imgv.setImageBitmap(image);

            }
            if( isNetworkConnected( )){

                new conn().execute("");

            }else{
            //  pd.dismiss(); 

    //      if(ROOT.endsWith("_s"))
    //      {
    //      
    //          
    //      }
                imgv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  // your code here
                    Log.d("inside onclick", "ok");
                    String _n=temp.replace("_s.jpg", "_n.jpg");
                    imageLoader2.DisplayImage(_n,imgv );
            //  imgv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

                 }
             });

            }

            //////////////////////// ADS ///////////////////////

         // Create the adView
            adView = new AdView(getActivity(), AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "a150f45ea765784");

            // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
            // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ADS);

            // Add the adView to it
            layout.addView(adView);

            // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    //////////////////////// END ADS ///////////////////////

           back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Fragment newFragment = new Gallery(getActivity());
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                    // and add the transaction to the back stack
                    transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
                 // transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                    // Commit the transaction
                  //  transaction.remove(mFragment);
                  transaction.commit();


                }
            });

            return rootView;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
final Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ROOT+String.valueOf(g.getId())+"q.jpg");
 Bitmap bitmapimage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 60, 60, true);
```

or you can call this method pass path of the image and size of width and height like 60 and 60

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(String path, int reqWidth,
            int reqHeight) {

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        return bmp;
        }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
             }
         }
         return inSampleSize;
        }
```

Comment: i have to put this piece of code ,or i must do some extra thing to make work?,, ive just put it and it doesn't work untill now

Comment: i put in 2 place and still not work ,, first i put under the bitmap declaration and second in else part and in each cases it doesn't work

Comment: then try this method to resize the image widht and height

Comment: thanks put my manager says that it's a large code we don't want to ad complicated  features thanks alot

Comment: Ohh that fineb but you should accept this answer this is the way only

Answer (score 0):

Use same code to create another bitmap of the image you want and assign it to your Imageview.

```
imgv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // your code here
         final Bitmap new_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ROOT+String.valueOf(g.getId())+"q.jpg");
         imgv.setImageBitmap(new_image);
        }
       });
```

Comment: i try to do this put it doesn't see the onclick method  ,, the log statement doesn't appears at log cat